# How to get variable sent by GET method (through AJAX)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need help with AJAX. I have a code, which loads .php file with some additional data. How can i use this data for loading new page?

The code is here:

```
function cancelRecommendation(idData) {
    $.get("cancel_recommendation.php", { id: idData })
    .done(function() {
        location.replace("company.php?id=38&recommended=cancel");
    });
}
```

I need to change `38` with `id (idData)` variable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do like this, concatenate the strings and variable:

```
location.replace("company.php?id="+idData+"&recommended=cancel");
```

Here `idData` is your variable.